# Posting a form within bootbox dialog back to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, post, bootbox

I have the following bootbox snippet in which I load the message via an ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $("#add-name").val(),
        success: function (data) {
            bootbox.dialog({
                message: data,
                title: "Floorplan Group",
                buttons: {
                    success: {
                        label: "OK",
                        className: "btn-success",
                        callback: function () {
                               //what to do here?
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This is what `data` returns, and is loaded in the body of my bootbox dialog.

```
@model Monitoring.ViewModels.NameViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddName", "Users", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal",}))
{    
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddName(NameViewModel model)
    {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                  //return error
            }
            //add into DB
            return View(model);
    }
```

How do I post the form back to my controller? What code is needed in the bootbox's callback such that it'll post my form back and if there are any errors in the ModelState, my bootbox dialog will remain open, otherwise the dialog will close as per normal.

Answer (score 0):

First in your view, you need to add the display for your validation error messages, here's the easiest way to have them all through `@Html.ValidationSummary()`, you can also consider to use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`. I added a id for the form for easier form post in javascript.

```
@model Monitoring.ViewModels.NameViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddName", "Users", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", @id="SomeFormId"}))
{     @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
}
```

I am not sure what's the name for your view above, so I name it "View1", in your controller, you need to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddName(NameViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         return View("View1", model); // pass the invalid model back to the form view
    }
    //add into DB
    return View(model);
}
```

And in your javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: $("#add-name").val(),
    success: function(data) {
        bootbox.dialog({
            message: data,
            title: "Floorplan Group",
            buttons: {
                success: {
                    label: "OK",
                    className: "btn-success",
                    callback: function() {
                        $("SomeFormId").submit(); // Post the form
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```